# How to center items in a css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to center items in my css grid but it does not seem possible. How can I make the last item center on the page if there aren't more items.

[image]

**Reproduction:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

.post-grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  align-items: flex-start;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.post {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(65, 131, 135, 0.19);
  background: #ccc;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" media="all" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="post-grid">
      <div class="post"></div>
      <div class="post"></div>
      <div class="post"></div>
      <div class="post">I want this square in the middle of the page</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [grid-column CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) shorthand property specifies a grid item's size and location within a grid column by contributing a line, a span, or nothing (automatic) to its grid placement, thereby specifying the inline-start and inline-end edge of its grid area.

The [:last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) CSS pseudo-class represents the last element of its type among a group of sibling elements.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

.post-grid {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  align-items: flex-start;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.post {
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(65, 131, 135, 0.19);
  background: #ccc;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.post:last-of-type{
   grid-column: 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
    <div class="post-grid">
      <div class="post"></div>
      <div class="post"></div>
      <div class="post"></div>
      <div class="post">I want this square in the middle of the page</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It works, but I don't really want to change my html to support it because its hard with dynamic content and needs to be responsive so I don't know which column should be in the middle for that user.

Comment: editted the code, it should be responsive without any changes to the html. using the :last-of-type pseudo class. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type

Comment: Yeah but it could be ass wel two items which needs to center, which now I think of it is not a grid anymore

Comment: I think it answered the original question but I think I will opt out of css grid here and go with the display:inline-block, text-align:center thing.

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-microservice-vzxsg?file=/src/styles.css

Thanks for your amazing answer!